# How do I create calender alarms using Applescript (using OSX Yosemite/Mavericks)?

Tags: applescript

I have an Applescript here that triggers when an ICS file has been dropped into a folder. All it does it imports the ICS file into the Calendar and then create alarms for each calendar entry.

This was working fine on Mountain Lion. But hasn't been working since Mavericks/Yosemite. The calendar entries are being imported. But no alarms are being created.

This is code I use to add the alarm:

```
tell application "Calendar"
    tell calendar "Home"
        delay 1
        set myevents to every event

        repeat with oneevent in myevents
            tell oneevent
                set mysummary to summary
                display dialog mysummary

                make new display alarm at end with properties {trigger interval:-30}
            end tell
        end repeat

    end tell
end tell
```

As you can see from the code, I am displaying the summary for the event just as a test. I just want to find out it's opening the correct event.

I've looked/searched for examples/documentation on the topic but hardly find anything recent (i.e. Mavericks and above).

Any ideas on how to fix my problem? Thanks a lot

Comment: Your script doesn't import any events. It loops through existing events.

Comment: it's not the whole code. I just showed the part where I'm having an error. but even then, it doesn't change the fact I cannot add alarms to existing events. Can you help? thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
tell application "Calendar"
    tell calendar "Home"
        repeat with oneevent in (get every event)
            tell oneevent
                set startDate to start date
                set newAlarm to make new display alarm at end of display alarms with properties {trigger date:startDate}
                set trigger interval of newAlarm to -30
            end tell
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```